# Numbering style of sections in appendix

Tags: numbering, appendices

I'm using `article` class in LaTeX and my document has many appendices. In the appendix section, the enumeration of appendices is in the form of "Appendix A" "Appendix B" ... But After "Appendix I" the next one is "Appendix 10".

How can I have a consistent format?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And you rather mean `numbering`, not `enumeration`.

Comment: This means that you have used (accidentally) a command which set the `\thesection` (most likely) to `\arabic{section}`.

Comment: What happens if you issue the command `\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}` *immediately before* the `\section` instruction that generates the tenth section in the appendix portion of your document?

Comment: `I` is the 9th character in the Latin alphabet, there must have been some command change  of `\thesection` after the 9th appendix section

Answer (score 2):

As Christian Hupfer has already commented, there must be something in your code -- somewhere between the ninth and tenth `\section` command in the appendix portion of your document -- that changes the section numbering style from `\Alph` (A, B, C, etc) to `\arabic` (1, 2, 3 , etc).

If you cannot spot and fix the offending piece of code, I suggest you insert the instruction

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
```

immediately before the `\section` instruction that generates the tenth appendix. The new instruction resets the numbering style.